# How to customise collection view cell as per the images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

Below is my code.i am able to load but some space between two cells.how to avoid.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [dashBoard_img count];
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dashBoard_img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return image.size;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout
interitemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    FMMosaicCellView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[FMMosaicCellView reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // float horizontal = 8.0;
    //float vertical = 15.0;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[dashBoard_img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.imageView.frame.origin.x, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
//    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(horizontal, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to avoid the insets.

Put this: `return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`

Instead of: `return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Demo....

**SWIFT** :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1

**OBJECTIVE C** :

https://github.com/eoghain/RBCollectionViewBalancedColumnLayout